# How to changes the default URL format in kohana 3.2.

Tags: php, css, kohana-3.2

How to changes the default URL format in kohana 3.2.

base/news/news_details to news/

```
Route::set('news_tracking2', 'news/news_details')
->defaults(array('controller' => 'news','action'  => 'index','method' => NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix the concepts. There is a routing that translates the incoming URL into `Request::controller-action`(1). And generate links for HTML (2).

1: For routes:

```
Route::set('second', 'awesome_news_prefix(/<id>(/<offseet>))', array('offset' => '[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?'))
   ->defaults(array(
      'controller' => 'news',
      'action'     => 'index',
      'id'  => NULL,
      'offset' => NULL,
   ));
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>(/<offseet>))))', array('controller' => '[a-z][^/\.]+', 'offset' => '[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?'))
   ->defaults(array(
      'controller' => 'news',
      'action'     => 'index',
      'id'  => NULL,
      'offset' => NULL,
   ));
```

2. link generation

   URL::site(Route::get('default')->uri(array('id' => 1)));

give result:  `http://example.com/news/index/1`

```
URL::site(Route::get('second')->uri(array('id' => 1)));
```

give result:  `http://example.com/awesome_news_prefix/1`